# How can I pass a value from an <option> tag to a PHP variable?

Tags: php, html

Basically, I have two dropdown lists on my page, both query the same database to populate themselves. What I want is for a use to be able to select an item in one of the dropdown lists, and then for the second dropdown list to show every other option except for what the user selected in the first dropdown list.
I don't want the page to be refreshed in the process, and I want to avoid Sessions/Cookies if possible.

The easiest way I can think to do this is by setting a variable when the user selects a thing in one of the lists, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to do this.

Comment: if you want to do this without a page refresh, you can't do it with just php.  You will need something like a javascript solution.

Answer (score 1):

**HTML sample**

```
<select id="select1" >
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
<select id="select2" >
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript**

```
 $("#select1").change(function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        $('#select2').children('option[value="' + val + '"]').attr('disabled', true);
        // or
        $('#select2').children('option[value="' + val + '"]').remove();
    })
```

[JSFIddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/dfv1zpxo/)